# Restore accidentally deleted Cloud Spanner instance

Tags: restore, google-cloud-spanner

My Spanner instance was accidentally deleted. Is there a way to restore the complete Cloud Spanner instance? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can request a restore within a (very short) number of days after deleting with a support request.

Cloud Spanner launched public preview of database deletion protection feature to help users prevent the accidental deletion of databases. Once the protection is enabled, IAM principals that have permission to delete databases can't delete protected databases. Users have to disable the protection first before attempting to delete the database which provides an additional layer of protection to prevent accidental deletions. If any of the databases in a Spanner instance has the protection enabled, then the instance is also protected from deletion automatically. Pls make use of this feature for preventing future accidental deletions. https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/prevent-database-deletion.